# How to get a post's details by shortcode?

Tags: posts, shortcode

It's probably simple. I'm looking for a simple shortcode that accepts a single post id variable, and pulls in title / permalink / excerpt and post thumbnail.

I know there are plugins out there that will handle this but they all seem like so much overkill.

Would love some help on this thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to write a shortcode add wrap a function around it:

```
function get_post_details($atts) {
    // Get the shortcode's attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'post' => 0,
    ), $atts, 'get-post-details' );
    // Fetch the ID from $atts array
    $id = $atts['post'];
    // Stop the shortcode if no ID is set
    if ($id == '0') return 'Please provide a post ID.';
    // Get the title for this post
    $data = get_the_title($id);
    // Get the permalink for this post
    $data .= get_the_permalink($id);
    // Get the thumbnail for this post
    $data .= get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id, 'thumbnail');
    // Return the data
    return $data;
}
add_shortcode( 'get-post-details', 'get_post_details' );
```

Now you can have a post's details by using `[get-post-details post="123"]`. If no ID is set, the details of the current post in the loop will be shown.

Comment: Ah I think i see where our going with this - however your function doesn't appear to be working in my functions.php - It's sending the site into a 500 error and I can't see to sort what's throwing it off.

Comment: @Tanmccuin Actually I have no idea why it's throwing a 500 error, that's weird. But I've added more conditionals to make sure attributes are set, preventing some errors.